# PassOptionsToPackage and knitr child documents

Tags: knitr, draft, rnw

I am using Knitr and the `standalone` version of `.RNW` files where I can compile either a [main document or work with and compile child documents individually](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/). Because of other packages, I would like to use the optional document class argument `draft`.

However, I do not want the functionality of the `draft` argument to be passed to the `graphicx` package.
I can avoid this by using the `PassOptionsToPackage` command before  `documentclass` and this works fine.

The problem is that the child document does not pass this option to `graphicx` and thus, when compiling the child document by itself I get draft outputs of the graphs.

How can I pass the `final` argument to the `graphicx` package in the child document?

My parent file `TestParent.RNW`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{graphicx}
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\begin{document}

This is text from the main file.

<<child, child='TestChild.RNW'>>=
@

This is also text from the main file.

\end{document}
```

[image: Parent output]

Child document `TestChild.RNW`.

```
<<set-parent_stocks, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
set_parent('TestParent.Rnw')
@

This chunk below is from the child document.

<<test-child, out.width='2in'>>=
plot(1:2)
@
```

[image: Child output]

Comment: What happens if you  add a second `\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{graphicx}` *after* `\documentclass[draft]{article}`.?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried but the output is unchanged. Should I add to the question that I have tried it?

Comment: And what happens if you add \usepackage[final]{graphicx}?

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have stated this. I cannot add the package since knitr adds `usepackage[]{graphicx}` right after the `documentclass` when it weaves the document and thus creates a clash of a package being loaded twice.

Comment: Then add `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` to your preamble (and hope that it gets after graphicx ;-)). Or perhaps better use `\AtBeginDocument{...}`.

Comment: `\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}` after the `documentclass` resolves the issue! I do not know how, though.

Comment: Do I just do `\AtBeginDocument{\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}}`? Either way, thanks for your answer. Can you post it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the draft key of graphics locally (for the following pictures) with

```
 \setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
```

So you only need to ensure that this commands comes after the loading of the graphicx package. From the comments I got that this here will work:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}
\begin{document}

This is text from the main file.

<<child, child='TestChild.RNW'>>=
@

This is also text from the main file.

\end{document}
```

But one can also delay the setting further by using `\AtBeginDocument{\setkeys{Gin}{draft=false}}` in the preamble instead.